# How to use replicated Infinispan cache in Wildfly standalone-full-ha

Tags: wildfly, infinispan

I would like to use a replicated Infinispan cache using two Wildfly standalone instances. I want to insert a value on one node and I should be able to read it on the other node.

Here's what I tried:

- I unzipped the full WF10 distribution using two different virtual
  maschines running Debian Jessie.
- I run both maschines with the standalone-full-ha.xml config.
- I changed the binding from localhost to the IP adresses of the VMs -
  all ports are reachable from outside.
- I added another cache by inserting the following code to the config:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">  
  <cache-container name="monitor" default-cache="default">  
    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>  
    <replicated-cache name="default" mode="SYNC">  
      <transaction mode="BATCH"/>  
    </replicated-cache>  
  </cache-container>  
...
```

- The rest of the configuration is not modified.
- On both nodes I get the following log entries (my interpretation is -
  both nodes see each other):

```
2016-03-13 11:19:43,160 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel monitor: [wf1|5] (2) [wf1, wf2]
```

- On one node I created a cache writer. On the other node a cache
  reader is deployed:

```java
@Singleton  
@Startup  
public class CacheWriter {  

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheWriter.class);  

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/monitor")  
    private EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager;  

    private Cache<String, String> cache;  

    @PostConstruct  
    public void init() {  
        cache = cacheManager.getCache();  
        LOG.info("Cache name: " + cache.getName());  
    }  

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "0", persistent = false)  
    public void createDateString() {  
        Long date = new Date().getTime();  
        updateCache("date", date.toString());  
    }  

    public void updateCache(String key, String value) {  
        if (cache.containsKey("date")) {  
            LOG.info("Update date value: " + value);  
            cache.put(key, value);  
        } else {  
            LOG.info("Create date value: " + value);  
            cache.put(key, value);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

```java
@Singleton  
@Startup  
public class CacheReader {  

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheReader.class);  

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/monitor")  
    private EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager;  

    private Cache<String, String> cache;  

    @PostConstruct  
    public void init() {  
        cache = cacheManager.getCache();  
        LOG.info("Cache name: " + cache.getName());  
    }  

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "10", persistent = false)  
    public void readDateString() {  
        LOG.info("Cache size: " + cache.keySet().size());  
        if (cache.containsKey("date")) {  
            LOG.info("The date value is: " + cache.get("date"));  
        } else {  
            LOG.warn("No date value found");  
        }  
    }  
}
```

The values on the writer are inserted but there are no cache modifications on the reader node and the cache size is always 0. I tried the TCP and the UDP stack. What am I missing? Can you help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does getCacheName return the same name? When I use cache manager I normally ask for an explicitly named cache

Comment: You could also try using one of the existing cache managers, e.g ejb

Comment: The cache name is the same on both nodes and changing the injected cache to ejb  doesn't help either - so no success.

Comment: You do have the wildfly nodes clustered right? It will only work in clustered mode. Just sanity checking here.

Comment: Yes, I use the standalone-full-ha.xml config and I think because of the log message above, that the cluster connection is established.

Comment: I can't see what is wrong right now, but I'd suggest you try either [this](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/jboss-as7) and see if that works. Alternatively, you could enable TRACE logging for org.infinispan package in the configuration file and follow the put operation...

Comment: I aslo have a similar problem. The same code works fine in WildFly9, but WildFly10 returns CacheManager without "named configurations". So every time you ask for a cache, you just receive a new default configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Try to directly inject a cache reference (not populating it through the CacheManager). As I understand, this is only way to compel infinispan container to start it in the new WildFly 10.

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/monitor/default")
private Cache<String, String> cache;
```

By careful with the JNDI name (default one) or specify it explicitly in configuration

Answer (score 1):

Instead of injecting `CacheManager` you should inject each cache instance. While doing, keep in mind the following points.

- Make sure to enter the correct JNDI name. To avoid any confusion you could explicitly mention the JNDI name in the configuration
- Add the `transport` tag to the `cache-container`. This is needed for replicated or distributed mode.

Sample Configuration in `standalone-full-ha.xml`

```
<cache-container name="replicated_cache" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server" jndi-name="infinispan/replicated_cache">
  <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
  <replicated-cache name="customer" mode="SYNC" jndi-name="infinispan/replicated_cache/customer">
    <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="FULL_XA"/>
    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
  </replicated-cache>
</cache-container>
```

Inject the resource as follows

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/replicated_cache/customer")
private Cache<String, Customer> customerCache;
```